# Extract a number from a consecutive range in a Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, performance, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new in coding and I use google script in my spreadsheet to add a list of consecutive numbers automatically by giving the first number to add and the last one (with an arrival date and an option "A" or "B" for each number). I created a table to put all the informations with an html file. The code is "OK", it's working but it's too slow and I reached my limits in coding to improve the code so...is there somebody that can help me or give an hint on that ?

To make the message clearer, here is what I have and what I want at the end :

Before launching the code :
[image]

After launching the code, completing the table (forget about the first line) :
[image]

Final result with consecutive range of number added :
[image]

Code.gs

```
function onOpen(e) {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
       .createMenu('Arrivage')
       .addItem('Add a new one', 'Arrivee')
       .addToUi();
 }

function Arrivee() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();
  if (sheet.indexOf("Br") == 0) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Vous devez sélectionner 
la feuille où ajouter l'arrivage et pas celle des colis !");
    return false 
  }else{  
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index.html')
.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
       .showModalDialog(html, 'Remplissez les infos 
nécessaires pour le nouvel arrivage des ' + sheet);
  }
}

function itemAdd(form) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var feuille = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var nb_total = form.colis2 - form.colis1;
  for (i = 0; i <= nb_total; i++) {
    if (i < form.gare){
      var a_values = [[ +form.colis1 + i, form.ddc, "A" ]];
      feuille.getRange(feuille.getLastRow() + 1, 6, 1, 3).setValues(a_values);
    }else{
      var b_values = [[ +form.colis1 + i, form.ddc, "B" ]];
      feuille.getRange(feuille.getLastRow() + 1, 6, 1, 3).setValues(b_values);   
    }   
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top" >
  </head>
  <form>
    Numéro arrivage :
    <input type="text" name="br">
    <br><br>
    Numéro colis 1 :
    <input type="text" name="colis1">
    <br><br>
    Numéro colis 2 :
    <input type="text" name="colis2">
    <br><br>
    Gare : 
    <input type="text" name="gare">
    <br><br>
    Date de création :
    <input type="text" name="ddc">
    <br><br>
     <input type="button" value="Ajouter"
        onclick="google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
            .itemAdd(this.parentNode)" />
    </form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the answer could be useful to someone that begin like me in coding...Anyway the tip here was to create an array first (I named it `table`) instead of adding objects line by line and then update the sheet in a single operation with `setValues`. It makes running the code way much faster !

```
function itemAdd(form) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var feuille = ss.getActiveSheet();      
  var nb_total = form.colis2 - form.colis1;
  var table = [];
  for (i = 0; i <= nb_total; i++) {
    if (i < form.gare){
      table.push([+form.colis1 + i, form.ddc, "A"]);
      }else{
      table.push([+form.colis1 + i, form.ddc, "B"]);
      }
    }
  feuille.getRange(feuille.getLastRow() + 1, 6, table.length, 3).setValues(table);
  }
```